# session.gc_maxlifetime на 365 дней

Tags: сессия, php

Чем чревато если в конфигах php установить время жизни сеесий на 365 дней? Собственно имеется ли у кого опыт проведения такого рода теста? Для `session.cookie_lifetime` задаем то же значение!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ничем хорошим это не чревато.
session.cookie_lifetime должно быт равно 0, т.е. до тех пор пока браузер не закрыт кукис будет жить. Чем чревато уставновка более длительного значения, тем что сессия будет теряться, поскольку все сессии сохраняются в папку tmp (переменная session.save_path), которая очищается от мусора. Хотите долго хранить этот мусор, используйя переменную session.save_path изменить папку для хранения сессий.

Comment: Ну как бы другая папка для хранения уже предусмотрена. По сути, мои тесты выше описанных установок в php.ini вполне себя оправдали, скажу что за 4 дня в куках была только записанна иниациализация сессии которая так же изменена от стандартной. Каких либо погрешностей я не увидел, сборщик мусора работает четко. Количество сессионых записей достигали более 40, и самое важное что они недоступны для изменения пользователем... Да, можно хранить все в БД, но тут важна конкретно инициализация.

Comment: за единственный ответ за 4 дня более чем благодарен!

Comment: Ммм, вдогонку вопрос, а чего ради эти тесты?

Comment: Планирую запустить портал с такой инициализацией, посмотреть что получится... на VDS места хватит под все... т.е. хранение сессионных файлов... Так же разгрузить запросы к бд ипрочее... еще не знаю на сколько это верный подход, но порой на грабли наступить есть смысл..

Comment: Если сравнить выборку из БД, например, по 100 000 записей и по выборке из аналогичного кол-ва файлов, быстрее будет работать БД и чем больше файлов, тем выигрышь с БД будет больше, т.е. в данном случае получается узкое место это работа с hdd (одно лечим другое колечим), а в случае портала со временем это самое кол-во будет неуклонно расти. Имхо, базу нужно разгружать от ресурсоъёмких запросов, а небольшие выборки сессионных данных нагрузки не создадут существенной.

Comment: явно учту... благодарен!

Answer (score 0):

Места на `VDS` может и хватит, а вот в `innode` упретесь довольно быстро, особенно, если портал будет очень посещаемый.

Comment: м.б. inode ( с одной n) ?